# Problems installing usvision

Tags: installation, vaio, tv

I am trying to install usbvision from [Sourceforge.net](http://usbvision.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=download) I am obviously doing something wrong

```
sudo apt-get install usbvision-0.9.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package usbvision-0.9.6
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'usbvision-0.9.6'
```

If you can help, I would be most grateful.

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on a Sony Vaio VGN-AR71E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think that you can install Usbvision on 13.04.  Here is why:

I wasn't able to download the version that you're trying to install, but I found [usbvision-0.9.8.3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/usbvision/files/?source=navbar), so after downloading, extracting, and trying to install, this is what I get:

```
abed@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ tar xvf usbvision-0.9.8.3.tar.gz 
usbvision/
usbvision/FAQ
usbvision/readme.2.6.x kernels
usbvision/src/
usbvision/src/Makefile
usbvision/src/saa7113-new.c
usbvision/src/Do_not_copy_Makefile_to_kernel_tree
usbvision/src/saa7113.c
usbvision/src/usbvision_ioctl.h
usbvision/src/usbvision.c
usbvision/src/saa7111-new.c
usbvision/src/usbvision.h
usbvision/src/bt819-new.c
usbvision/src/i2c-algo-usb.h
usbvision/src/i2c-algo-usb.c
usbvision/xawtv-config-example
usbvision/readme.2.4.x kernels
usbvision/COPYING
abed@ubuntu:~/Downloads/usbvision/src$ make
Makefile:30: *** Aborting the build. *** Kernel version 3.8.0-19-generic is not supported.  Stop.
```

So I think for you to install Usbvision, you either have to downgrade your Kernel, or maybe try an older version of Ubuntu, but then it probably won't be supported.